# Вызов чанка из сниппета

Tags: modx

Добрый день.

Вопрос к тем, кто работал на Modx и писал сниппеты.
Написал такой код в сниппете:

```
<?php
echo "Сниппет PrintChunk работает!";
$output = $modx->getChunk($chank);
return $output;
```

Создал такой параметр `$chank` и вызываю потом следующим образом:

```
[[!PrintChunk? &chank=`tell_my`]]
```

И ничего не выводит из чанка, кроме Сниппет PrintChunk работает! Как же вывести чанк из сниппета? Документация показывает, как будто я все правильно пишу, хотя на деле не работает это все… Не знаю даже, что делать-то. Смотрел примеры тут: [ссылка](http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/developing-in-modx/other-development-resources/class-reference/modx/modx.getchunk).

**Обновление**

Переписал через pdoTools сниппет и вызов чанка, и все равно не работает как надо. Привожу код:

```
$pdo = $modx->getService('pdoTools');
$tpl = $modx->getOption($chank, $scriptProperties, '@INLINE array(\'id\'=>\'[[+id]]\'); '); 
$return='';
$return .= $pdo->getChunk($tpl, array('id'=>'1'));
return $return;
```

Вызываю таким же образом:

```
[[!PrintChunk? &chank=`tell_my`]]
```

На вывод получаю не содержимое чанка (а там форма), а вывод массива, какой указал в сниппете, то есть следующее:

```
array('id'=>'1');
```

В чем может быть проблема? Кто подскажет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение нашлось). Вот, может, кому пригодится:

```
$pdo = $modx->getService('pdoTools');  
return $pdo->getChunk($chank, array('id'=>'1'));
```

И вызываем потом этот сниппет:

```
[[!PrintChunk? &chank=`tell_my`]]
```

Правда, тут не используется INLINE биндинг.

P.S. Вопрос такой еще, почему не могу сам себе отмечать верный ответ? Это вопрос к администраторам сайта или модераторам.